# Clojure/Incanter scatter-plot: controlling size of points

Tags: clojure, incanter

I am plotting a scatter-plot, using Clojure and Incanter.
I need to control the size of the points in the graph/plot.

This is the basic code that I have.  I am using a different domain and range for my data, but the question is the same.  This plots without errors.

```
(doto (scatter-plot (range 10) (range 10))
      (set-stroke-color java.awt.Color/blue)
      view)
```

But, what would be the code to modify the size of the points being plotted?
I have attempted the line:

```
(set-point-size :point-size 1)
```

but when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: 1
```

I have a feeling that `:point-size` is the incorrect term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just delete `:point-size`, i.e. use `(set-point-size my-chart 1)`, or:

```
(doto (scatter-plot (range 10) (range 10))
      (set-stroke-color java.awt.Color/blue)
      (set-point-size 1)
      view)
```